# insert into sql database from selecting columns from excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I tried using insert into.. select method as below to insert the data from excel into sql,

```
Insert into table_fruits(type, weight, cut, date_import)
    SELECT type, weight, 'Yes', GetDate()
        from openrowset('MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0'),'Excel 8.0; 
            Database=D:\fruits.xls;HDR=YES','SELECT * from [SheetName$]'
```

but i got an error saying

```
    Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    OLE DB provider 'MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distribution queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode`
```

Is it possible to do this import without installing anything? since I read somewhere that people install something for 64-bit to solve.
or can i use provide sql query in import export wizard? I used the below query and it says that it is not an sql query

```
Insert into table_fruits(type, weight, cut, date_import)
    SELECT type, weight, 'Yes', GetDate()
        from [SheetName$]
```

would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using Import and export wizard

Comment: @Srini131 I tried using `Insert into table_fruits(type, weight, cut, date_import) SELECT type, weight, 'Yes', GetDate()  from [SheetName$]` in import wizard using sql query but it says syntax error in insert into statement. why?

Comment: Does the data exists only in One sheet in excel

Comment: @Srini131 yes. but it says there is a syntax error and i cant find it

Comment: Try to import data directly into temp staging table with out Query And insert data from temp table to your main table

Comment: INSERT INTO table_fruits(type, weight, cut, date_import) 
SELECT [type], [weight], 'Yes', GetDate() --Instead of date_import Column data from table use getdate()
FROM Stg_temptable

Comment: @Srini131 ya. i figured it the getdate() problem. but i don quite understand what `use getdate() FROM Stg_temptable` means?

Comment: i thought that if you need current date instead of date from column